# Visualize the tetrahedra with infinite vertices in MeshLab

Tags: cgal, meshlab, tetrahedra

I use the sample code to compute the tetrahedra for 6 vertices. The returned faces contain not only the input vertices, but infinite ones as well. This creates a problem of visualisation in MeshLab. I was wondering how I can get around this?

The sample code is as follows

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::list<Point> L;
    L.push_front(Point(0,0,0));
    L.push_front(Point(1,0,0));
    L.push_front(Point(0,1,0));
    Triangulation T(L.begin(), L.end());
    int n = T.number_of_vertices();

    std::vector<Point> V(3);
    V[0] = Point(0,0,1);
    V[1] = Point(1,1,1);
    V[2] = Point(2,2,2);
    n = n + T.insert(V.begin(), V.end());

    assert( n == 6 );
    assert( T.is_valid() );

    Locate_type lt;
    int li, lj;
    Point p(0,0,0);

    Cell_handle c = T.locate(p, lt, li, lj);
    assert( lt == Triangulation::VERTEX );
    assert( c->vertex(li)->point() == p );

    Vertex_handle v = c->vertex( (li+1)&3 );
    Cell_handle nc = c->neighbor(li);
    int nli;
    assert( nc->has_vertex( v, nli ) );

    std::ofstream oFileT("output",std::ios::out);
    oFileT << T;
    Triangulation T1;
    std::ifstream iFileT("output",std::ios::in);
    iFileT >> T1;
    assert( T1.is_valid() );
    assert( T1.number_of_vertices() == T.number_of_vertices() );
    assert( T1.number_of_cells() == T.number_of_cells() );

    std::cout << T.number_of_vertices() << " " << T.number_of_cells() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the output file is

```
3
6
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 1
1 1 1
2 2 2
11
1 0 3 4
2 1 3 4
0 2 3 4
1 5 6 4
2 3 1 0
1 2 5 4
5 2 6 4
6 2 0 4
1 6 0 4
1 2 0 6
1 2 6 5
2 1 8 4
0 2 5 4
1 0 7 4
6 8 5 10
0 9 2 1
6 3 1 10
7 3 5 10
2 8 6 9
7 0 3 9
7 8 10 4
6 3 5 9
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manual of class Triangulation_3
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__3.html
look for section I/O and read the description of the iostream.

In your example, there are 11 cells
  1 0 3 4
  2 1 3 4
  0 2 3 4
  1 5 6 4
  2 3 1 0
  1 2 5 4
  5 2 6 4
  6 2 0 4
  1 6 0 4
  1 2 0 6
  1 2 6 5

The infinite vertex has index 0. The 6 finite vertices are numbered 1 to 6. Their coordinates are at the top of your file (starting after the 6)

So you can filter out the cells having 0 as vertex, which gives you 5 tetrahedra
  2 1 3 4
  1 5 6 4
  1 2 5 4
  5 2 6 4
  1 2 6 5